# Ethereum source code build in Windows

Tags: go-ethereum

I have downloaded the ethereum source from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum, is there anyway to build the source in windows 10 machine. As per the document it says use make geth , but it will work in ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Go and configuring it (GOROOT and GOPATH) You could install and use "make" for windows to build the source.
Hope that this could help you!